# Visual Studio 2013 can't browse to C:\Windows\System32 subdirectory to add additional library directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My application depends on OpenSSL and I have put the OpenSSL libs in a subdirectory of C:\Windows\System32.

When I attempt to browse to that subdirectory via Linker->General->Additional Library Directories the directory is not visible in the dialogue box. All the other directories are visible.

Furthermore, if I just add the directory rather than browse to it, the linker doesn't find the library. It's like Visual Studio can't see the directory I've added.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: have you tried running as admin?

Comment: My account is an admin account. I was able to create the directory after all.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The application won't have admin privileges unless you give it those privileges.

Comment: Libraries don't belong in the operating system directory.  Put it anywhere, except c:\windows\system32.  Just in case: link the .lib file, not the .dll

Comment: @Boumbles How do I give the application admin privileges?

Comment: @Hans Passant When OpenSSL is installed, the installer offers the option to copy the DLLs to the Windows system directory. I didn't select the option at the time but I copied them myself later.

Comment: @user3139278 that's something you can ask Google.

Comment: @Boumbles Fair point.

Comment: @Boumbles Running Visual Studio as admin didn't make any difference. I still can't browse to the Windows\System32 subdirectory I created. I've put the libs elsewhere instead.